# What is the name of this property in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[how to shift the hint text to border while text field is selected? For example, in this picture hint text 'email or phone' gets shifted to border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N83Af.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FloatingLabelBehavior is the property you are looking for. Just set the `floatingLabelBehavior` of your `TextFormField` to `floatingLabelBehavior.always`. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/floatingLabelBehavior.html)

Comment: best solution to achieve the same effect i found out was to use label text instead of hint text